# Sort what is shown when Mysql table is presented on webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which has PHP forms adding content to this database table. I then have a page which shows the table so the people imputing can see the data. All the entries are times.

The down side to this is that there is a lot of blank spaces or 00:00:00 which makes the screen a bit confusing to read.

Is there a way to hide any columns without any times in until a time is inserted?

This is my Code

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '*********';
$db_pwd = '*******';

$database = '********';
$table = 'checkpoints';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        if $cell="<td>00:00:00</td>" then echo"<td></td>" Else echo"<td>$cell</td>";

echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: add an if statement to your foreach which checks if $cell is 00:00:00, and if so, dont echo it.

Comment: If you hide a column, the remaining columns in that row will be in the wrong position. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: ideally if there is nothing other that 00:00:00 in the entire column then hide it but just hiding the 00:00:00 is a start. Does anyone know of a tutorial on if statements? i'm rather new to this

Comment: read the official php documentation or check w3schools

Comment: ok I've done some googleing and tweeked the echo "<td>$cell</td> line to if $cell="<td>00:00:00</td>" then echo"<td></td>" Else echo"<td>$cell</td>"; but this just gives me a white page. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Ive got it working now thanks Ollie, Proved really helpfull

After some tweeking i found a rouge { which was causing my wsod

Here is my end code which I changed

```
foreach ($row as $cell) if ('00:00:00'==$cell){echo "<td></td>";} else {echo "<td>$cell</td>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this code

```
 foreach($row as $cell)
    if $cell="<td>00:00:00</td>" then echo"<td></td>" Else echo"<td>$cell</td>";
```

There's no way `$cell` will ever have the value `<td>00:00:00</td>`.  Plus you're using a single equal sign, which assigns that value to `$cell`.

Try this instead.

```
 foreach ( $row as $cell ) {
    if ( '00:00:00' == $cell ) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    }
```

When you get a blank browser screen from a php program you're debugging, always try View Source...

Comment: Thanks but im still getting a white screen... gone to view source and i just get a blank page again.